# Handle checkboxes with useState object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript, object

I have some checkboxes displayed using `.map()` function which is retrieving the data from a **JSON** file.

What i have achieved so far, is to store the clicked checkbox into the state (which is an object). But after I click another checkbox, it removes the previous one and store the latest..

I basically want to store all the checked ones, and if you remove them to remove it from the state.

Here's my `handleCheck()` function:

```
const handleCheckInput = (
      e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
      key: number,
      questionId: number,
   ) => {
      let newTickArray = [...tick];
      newTickArray[key] = !tick[key];
      setTick(newTickArray);
      setValues({ ...values, [questionId]: e.target.value });
   };
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

#### Update:

Changed `[questionId]: e.target.checked` to `[questionId]: e.target.value`.

#### Answer:

Here is how you do it (I used ellipsis `...` for parts that don't need to be changed and also for brevity):

(Also remember to use `e.target.checked` - the right property for checkbox elements - instead of `e.target.value`).

```
const handleCheckInput = (
  e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
  key: number,
  questionId: number) => {
    ... 

    if (e.target.checked) {
        setValues({ ...values, [questionId]: e.target.value});
    } else {
        // Remove unchecked from state.
        let { [questionId]: deletedKey, ...restOfObj } = values;
        setValues(restOfObj);
    }
};
```

Comment: this code is just onCheck returns true to the state...and not the actual value of the checkbox

Comment: @kukri do you mean you don't need the `checked` value?

Comment: no i mean i need it, but the `state` returns `true` or `false` when i check the checkboxes..i need to retrieve the `actual data` not the `true` or `false`

Comment: also it is still adding the latest checked value only

Comment: Okay, sorry for that mixup, I've changed `[questionId]: e.target.checked` to `[questionId]: e.target.value`.

Comment: thats ok..do you have any idea how to store all the values to the object {} ?

Comment: Yes, the answer as it is now already does that, I tested it on my end. Doesn't it work the same for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244946/discussion-between-chizaram-igolo-and-kukri).